# There is no stub implementation for the interface error while creating stub

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am new to web service .

I have to consume the RPC XML SOAP web service , i just tried to create the stubs and locators through the wsdl provided by the web service provider .
Now when i am creating the object of XXXstub class in order to call the service method . i get Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: There is no stub implementation for the interface.

below is the code where i am trying to create the locator and stub object to call service method.

final EDWebService_ServiceLocator locator=new EDWebService_ServiceLocator();
final EDWebServiceSoapBindingStub stub=(EDWebServiceSoapBindingStub) locator.getPort(EDWebService_Service.class);

checked further it goes in getPort() and stuck in the if condition of the method.

Any help/clue related to this is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide the WSDL location as well.

Since, the implementation(that is, the original web service)  is located remotely (which you access using the WSDL), you need to provide this reference to identify the location where Web service is hosted.

I guess, you will have a getPort() method that accepts the url to WSDL. Please use that method.

Comment: getPort() accepts param as 

public java.rmi.Remote getPort(Class serviceEndpointInterface)